# In R, how do you dereference/decompose/expand a list to fill multiple arguments

Tags: r, list, types, shiny

I'm running into an issue with lists that I can't get around. I've tried unlist, lapply, and a number of other approaches with no success. In other languages, I would say I need to dereference the array, though that language isn't used in R very much.

This code works:

```
tabsetPanel( 
        tabPanel("P1" uiOutput("out1")), 
        tabPanel("P2", uiOutput("out2")) 
        )
```

Yet, I need to dynamically create the tabs so that this should work:

```
tabs = list( tabPanel("P1" uiOutput("out1")), 
             tabPanel("P2", uiOutput("out2")) )
tabsetPanel( SOMETHING )
```

The following do not work:

```
tabsetPanel( tabs )    
tabsetPanel( lapply(1:2, function(i)tabs[[i]] ) 
tabsetPanel( unlist(tabs) )
```

Comment: Look up `do.call`.

Comment: Perfect. do.call exactly works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `do.call` will do the trick:

```
do.call(tabsetPanel, args=tabs)
```

This function takes a function as its main argument and also takes a list in the args argument to feed the function.